# Image clustering and Dirichlet process

Tags: image-processing, dirichlet-process

I am reading a paper about the Dirichlet process and image segmentation.
(http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2404806)

How is (3) below derived? Do any articles or posts explain image segmentation and the Dirichlet process?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the *Law of Total Probability*:
$$
p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi) = \int p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi, \theta_k) \, \mathrm{d} \theta_k,
$$
for which we can rewrite by the definition of *conditional probability*
$$
p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi, \theta_k) = p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi \mid \theta_k) \, p(\theta_k),
$$
to get the final product
$$
\begin{align}
p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi) &=  \int p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi, \theta_k) \, \mathrm{d} \theta_k
\\
&= \int p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi \mid \theta_k) \, p(\theta_k) \, \mathrm{d} \theta_k
\\
&= \int \left\{ \prod_{x_n \in \boldsymbol X_k^\phi} p(x_n \mid \theta_k) \right\} \, p(\theta_k) \, \mathrm{d} \theta_k.
\end{align}
$$
Observe that because we believe the points $x_n$ are assigned clusters *independently*, we can rewrite
$$
p(\boldsymbol X_k^\phi \mid \theta_k) = \prod_{x_n \in \boldsymbol X_k^\phi} p(x_n \mid \theta_k).
$$